# How to add a partially transparent image to Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am making a game in Tkinter and I would really like partially transparent images in the game for obvious reasons...

How would I do that? PNG doesn't allow transparency, and JPEG does allow transparency but isn't considered an 'image file'... What file type would allow that? Can I use bitmap somehow to make a JPEG useable? Thanks!

Some use info:

I started learning Python 3 months ago and am not horribly good, but I do know classes, functions, and how to make stuff in Tkinter. I also obviously know a lot more, but as I said I am not too terribly good at it. Thanks!

Comment: have added minimal example of code :). tell me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Tkinter does recognise .ico files, but I have never used them apart from as an icon at the top left.

I would use a GIF file, and `tk.PhotoImage` to display it. This does allow for transparent images to be shown:

My Proof:

[image]

The image in a tk window, but when I change the background colour to say yellow, the button background is the same as the tk window background, so it is transparent.

[image]

**EDIT: HERE IS CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = "FILENAME.gif")
label1 = tk.Button(image = image1)
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

hope that helps you.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work for me, could it be my image editing software? I've tried used Gimp 2 and paint.net, exporting as a .gif everytime.

Comment: Hunter Kepley, I could show the code if that is handy?

Comment: No problem, go ahead.

Comment: It might be because I don't use pack, what does pack do?                                                                           And what image editor do you use?

Comment: @hunter `.pack()` is a method for putting widgets in a window, others are `.place()` and `.grid()`. As for image editing software, I got this image off the internet, but have used Adobe Photoshop and then converted the file to GIF online.

Comment: I'll try just getting an image online real fast, it could be they aren't saving properly with paint.net which has never been a problem before..  EDIT -- Did not work, I am really not sure what is happening.

Comment: @hunter show us your code that you are trying to work with, how doesn't it work, not transparent, not showing at all etc...

Comment: @W1llamvl I posted an answer below containing it.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Could you test the solution against having some text on the underlying surface under the leaf picture? Demonstrated `root["bg"] = "yellow"` proves the transprency channel in the picture, however the Tkinter layout-management seems to be IMHO the harder part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

startpic = PhotoImage(file = "ddsp.gif")
startbut = PhotoImage(file = "start.gif")
helpbut = PhotoImage(file = "help.gif")
exitbut = PhotoImage(file = "exit.gif")

root.geometry("640x480")
root.title("Deep Death")
root.resizable(0,0)

starter = Label(image = startpic)
starter.pack()

start = Label(image = startbut)
start.place(x=340,y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

Even though the .gifs' are transparent, they are appearing with a white background.

Comment: As a general principle, you shall avoid using more than one `<GeometryLayoutMANAGER>` from the set of available `{ .pack() | .grid() | .place() }` in a Tkinter GUI, once composing the Widgets together.

Comment: @user3666197: that's a bad general principle. In fact, I would go so far as to say the general rule is to always use more than one. They each have strengths and weaknesses. The only caveat is you can't use two different managers with widgets that share the same parent.m

Comment: I only use more than one for stuff like background images, canvas is good for those. But how come using canvas I can input partially transparent images, but with pack grid or place they aren't transparent? I need to know because buttons aren't in canvas and I need to make a button partially transparent. Help!

Comment: @BryanOakley Love the accent to a purity of your texts. Isn't that the very case that both `starter.pack()` and `start.place()` do share the same common `root`-parent, that you insist on being avoided as The Caveat?

Comment: @HunterKepley Ok i understand what you mean now. The background of the image is transparent, but is still part of the image, and thus the label, which is rectangular, is given a grey background (normal tk window colour) so that the latest positioned label appears to be 'on top', and it's background blocks some of the other label out. I have no idea how to get around this in tkinter, it might be possible, but you might have to use another GUI toolkit?

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Yes that is exactly the problem. My solution is to get the background color from where it is, crop and paste it into another window and make it that way. I am going to probably switch to pygame or pygtk+ later, but for now this works. Thanks for trying! :)

Comment: @user3666197: yes, start and starter share the same parent and thus should use the same geometry manager. In this _specific_ case one should stick to a single manager, but in _general_ you should mix and max in order to use the right tool for the job.